# Apply Order Number Prefix For Orders Container Recurring / Nominal Products

Tags: orders, sales-order, recurring, increment-id, nominal-product

I am in the process of trying to highlight specific orders containing recurring / nominal products to an admin user as well as inside a data feed that exports order data on a daily basis to a fulfilment center.

Is there a way that I can apply an order prefix or suffix to any order containing a recurring / nominal product? Would this have a knock-on effect on the incremental value for future orders that are placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'sales_order_place_after' to check payment type for the order after that using following tutorial you can change the order id for that order
 https://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Comment: Worked really well. Thanks for your help :-)